# Is the /opt directory empty by default in macOS Big Sur 11.4?

Tags: terminal, directory, macos

I am currently on **macOS Big Sur 11.4**, and I have noticed that my **/opt** directory is empty.

I opened the **Terminal** application and typed `cd /opt`. I then typed `ls`, but it did not show any files or directories.

This left me wonder whether the **/opt** directory is supposed to have certain directories and/or files or is supposed to be empty.

Comment: Probably a better question for ask different

Comment: What have you searched for or researched to try to find he answer on your own? There are many documents on the web regarding Unix-style directory structures and layouts.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem which does not exist - I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's empty by default. `/opt` is for add-on software packages. It is by definition, things that don't come with the OS.

Strictly speaking, whenever you've used `/usr/local`, according to a strict reading of the filesystem hierarchy standard, that probably should have gone in `/opt` instead. Comparatively, `/usr/local` is for "local data, specific to this host".

For some historical context, when NFS was highly popular, some organizations would have `/` and/or `/usr` mounted via NFS so they could have a consistent set of software installed for the entire org. `/usr/local` then would be mounted from the *local* (i.e., physically attached) storage of that machine. It was for things specific to that machine that did not apply to every other machine in the org.

If you feel the distinction between `/opt` and `/usr/local` is very subtle, you're not alone.

Since macOS started shipping with SIP (**S**ystem **I**ntegrity **P**rotection), `/usr` is read-only on new systems and you can't even create `/usr/local` (maybe this has changed, but IIRC this was the case at least for first release with SIP). Systems upgrading from an earlier version of macOS that did have `/usr/local` could still write to it.

If you have `/usr/local`, feel free to use it for whatever you want. If you're an application developer, don't count on being able to write to `/usr/local` on macOS. But regardless, on any Unix (or Unix-like) system, prefer `/opt` over `/usr/local`.